# Regex for email in Mysql in between any number of characters

Tags: mysql, regex, email

I am trying to create a regex which identifies an email between a long string.
The below regex works fine for email :

```
^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$
```

But I need to create a regex such that this should return true :

```
SELECT 'hfdjj abc@enmail.com jkdfk' REGEXP '^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$';
```

I want to have any number of characters before and after the email.

Thanks,
Aman

Comment: replace the anchors with `.*`

Comment: if you want to learn something about recognizing email adress, have a look at [this piece of art](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regex-use-vs-regex-abuse/)... Or if you want to keep it simple, just remove `^` and `$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're happy with the matching of the email, simply removing the `^` and `$` characters from the start and end should suffice.

`^` matches the beginning of the string.
`$` matches the end of the string.

Between them, they are what's telling MySQL to not match where there are things either side of the email address.